# How to create Extended Data for KML exported from shapefile by ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-desktop, kml, convert, google-earth

I have a GIS shapefile of 300+ points that I am **[converting to KML using ArcGIS for Desktop](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s200000009000000)**. Once in KML I want to create custom balloons by editing the KML file.  However, the HTML feature in ArcGIS does not set up the Schema and Extended Data that I need (e.g. if I open a shapefile in Google Earth Pro and save it as KML, it creates the Schema and Extended Data automatically). I don't have access to Google Earth Pro right now. Is there another way to create this in ArcGIS or is there a 3rd party program that will do this? I don't have much programming experience, so I can't really go that route. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might try Google Fusion Tables, which accepts geographic data as a CSV file and provides mapping and export to KML (with or without NetworkLink) functionality. I do not know if it will create ExtendedData elements for every attribute field in your CSV.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the "Data Interoperability" extension, you should be able to output a KML file from your layer using the “Quick Export” tool which exports also the extended data.

There are also several ArcScript tools available to export to KML from ArcGIS (see **[here](http://arcscripts.esri.com/scripts.asp?pg=1&sb=1&ob=asc&eDate=&n=&top=&eLang=&eProd=&perPage=10&eQuery=KML)**).

Comment: Link is busted. https://geonet.esri.com/thread/182094-please-restore-arcscripts just Google it